# Salesforce/PHP - outbound messages (SOAP) - memory limit issue? DOMDocument::loadXML() Premature end of data in tag issue?

Tags: php, soap, salesforce, domdocument, memory-limit

UPDATE:

OK I figured it out, looks like fread has a filesize limitation, changed this to

`file_get_contents('php://input')`

, but now having SF give a java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out error and nothing on the PHP side. I have also added set_time_limit(0); to the PHP script which if I understand correctly execute the script for as long as it takes. Any thoughts?

BTW: I can process up to 25 (that I've tested) but not 100

---

I'm using Salesforce to send outbound messages (via SOAP) to another server. The server can process about 8 messages at a time, but will not send back the ACK file if the SOAP request contains more than 8 messages. SF can send up to 100 outbound messages in 1 SOAP request and I think this is causing a memory issue with PHP. If I process the outbound messages 1 by 1 they all go through fine, I can even do 8 at a time with no issues. But larger sets are not working.

ERROR in SF:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file
```

Looking in the HTTP error logs I see that the incoming SOAP message looks to be getting cut of which throws a PHP warning stating:

```
DOMDocument::loadXML() ... Premature end of data in tag ...
```

PHP Fatal error:

```
Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object
```

This leads me to believe that PHP is having a memory issue and can not parse the incoming message due to it's size.

I was thinking I could just set:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M'); // This has done nothing to fix the problem
```

But would this be the correct approach? Is there a way I could set this to increase with the incoming SOAP request dynamically?

UPDATE: Adding some code

```
 /**
 * To parse out incoming SOAP requests and insert the values into a database table
 * 
 * {@link http://www.mikesimonds.com/salesforce-php-tutorials/95-using-salesforce-outbound-soap-messages-php-2.html}
 */

// Might need more memory?
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M'); // So far this does nothing to help the bulk requests

/**
 * Set the document root path
 * @var $doc_root
 */
$doc_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];


/**
 * This is needed for the $sObject object variable creation
 * found in phptoolkit-11_0 package available from SalesForce
 */
require_once(DOC_ROOT . SALESFORCE_DIRECTORY . SALESFORCE_PHP_TOOLKIT .'/soapclient/SforcePartnerClient.php'); 

/**
 * Reads SOAP incoming message from Salesforce/MAPS
 * @var incoming SOAP request
 */
$data = fopen('php://input','rb');

$headers = getallheaders();
$content_length = $headers['Content-Length'];
$buffer_length = 1000; // Do I need this buffer? 
$fread_length = $content_length + $buffer_length;

$content = fread($data,$fread_length);

/**
 * Parse values from soap string into DOM XML
 */
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($content);
$resultArray = parseNotification($dom);
$sObject = $resultArray["sObject"];

// Can remove this once I figure out the bug
$testing = false;

// Set $testing to true if you would like to see the incoming SOAP request from SF
if($testing) {
    // Make it look nice
    $dom->formatOutput = true;

    // Write message and values to a file
    $fh = fopen(LOG_FILE_PATH.'/'.LOG_FILE_NAME,'a');
    fwrite($fh,$dom->saveXML());
    $ret_val = fclose($fh);
}

/**
 * Checks if the SOAP request was parsed out,
 * the $sObject->ACK is set to a string value of true in
 * the parseNotification()
 * @var $sObject->ACK
 */
if($sObject->ACK == 'true') {
    respond('true');
} else {
    // This means something might be wrong
    mail(BAD_ACK_TO_EMAIL,BAD_ACK_EMAIL_SUBJECT,$content,BAD_ACK_EMAIL_HEADER_WITH_CC);
    respond('false');
}

if(WRITE_OUTPUT_TO_LOG_FILE) {
    // Clear variable
    $fields_string = "";

    /**
     * List common values of the SOAP request
     * @var $sObject
     */
    $fields_string .= "Organization Id: " . $sObject->OrganizationId . "\n";
    $fields_string .= "Action Id: " . $sObject->ActionId . "\n";
    //$fields_string .= "Session Id: " . $sObject->SessionId . "\n"; // Session Id is not being passed right now, don't need it
    $fields_string .= "Enterprise URL: " . $sObject->EnterpriseUrl . "\n";
    $fields_string .= "Partner URL: " . $sObject->PartnerUrl . "\n"; 

    /**
     * @todo: Still need to add the notification Id to an array or some sort
     */
    //$fields_string .= "Notification Id: " . $sObject->NotificationId . "\n"; 
    //$fields_string .= '<pre>' . print_r($sObject->NotificationId,true) . '</pre>';

    /**
     * now you have an array as $record and you can use the
     * data as you need to for updates or calls back to salesforce
     * whatever you need to do is here
     * @var $resultArray['MapsRecords']
     */
    foreach ($resultArray['MapsRecords'] as $record) {
        // Just prints the fields in the array
        $fields_string .= '<pre>' . print_r($record,true) . '</pre>';  
    }

    // Flag used to send ACK response
    $fields_string .= "\nACK Flag: " . $sObject->ACK;

    // $content_length
    $fields_string .= "\nContent Length (Outbound Message Size): " . $content_length;

    // Close Border to separate each request
    $fields_string .= "\n /*********************************************/ \n";

    // Write message and values to a file
    $fh = fopen(LOG_FILE_PATH.'/'.LOG_FILE_NAME,'a');
    fwrite($fh,$fields_string);
    $ret_val = fclose($fh); 
}

/**
 * Parse a Salesforce.com Outbound Message notification SOAP packet
 * into an array of notification parms and an sObject. 
 * @param   XML [$domDoc] SOAP request as XML
 * @return  object/array[ $result] typecast XML to object of arrays
 **/
function parseNotification($domDoc) {  
    // Parse Notification parameters into result array
    $result = array("OrganizationId" => "",
                    "ActionId" => "",
                    "SessionId" => "",
                    "EnterpriseUrl" => "",
                    "PartnerUrl" => "",
                    "sObject" => null,
                    "MapsRecords" => array());

    // Create sObject and fill fields provided in notification
    $sObjectNode = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName("sObject")->item(0);
    $sObjType = $sObjectNode->getAttribute("type");

    if(substr_count($sObjType,"sf:")) {
        $sObjType = substr($sObjType,3);
    }

    $result["sObject"] = new SObject($sObjType);
    $result["sObject"]->type = $sObjType;    
    $result["sObject"]->OrganizationId = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName("OrganizationId")->item(0)->textContent;
    $result["sObject"]->ActionId = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName("ActionId")->item(0)->textContent;
    $result["sObject"]->SessionId = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName("SessionId")->item(0)->textContent;
    $result["sObject"]->EnterpriseUrl = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName("EnterpriseUrl")->item(0)->textContent;
    $result["sObject"]->PartnerUrl = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName("PartnerUrl")->item(0)->textContent;

    /**
     * @todo: for multiple requests, need to add an array of Notification Id's
     *        might move this inside the loop or something
     *        might not need to do this as well
     */
    //$notificationId[] = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName("Id")->item(0)->textContent;
    //$result["sObject"]->NotificationId = $notificationId;

    $sObjectNodes = $domDoc->getElementsByTagNameNS('urn:sobject.BLAH.com','*');
    $result["sObject"]->fieldnames = array();
    $count = 0;
    $tempMapRecord = array();

    // Loop through each notification sObject
    foreach ($sObjectNodes as $node) {
        if ($node->localName == "Id") {
            if ($count > 0) {
                $result["MapsRecords"][] = $tempMapRecord;
                $tempMapRecord = array();                          
            }
            // @note: added the strip_tags() to strip out all HTML tags
            $tempMapRecord[$node->localName] = strip_tags($node->textContent);
        } else {
            // @note: added the strip_tags() to strip out all HTML tags
            $tempMapRecord[$node->localName] = strip_tags($node->textContent);
        }        
        $count++;

        // set flag for ACK
        $result["sObject"]->ACK = 'true';
    }
    // Finish last item
    $result["MapsRecords"][] = $tempMapRecord;

    return $result;
}

/**
 * ACK to SalesForce, True/False (Prints header)
 * @param object $tf
 * @return $ACK
 */
function respond($tf) {
    $ACK = <<<ACK
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <notifications xmlns="http://BLAH.com/outbound">
            <Ack>$tf</Ack>
        </notifications>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
ACK;

    print trim($ACK); 
}
```

Example SOAP Request from Salesforce, there would be multiple notification nodes added to a larger request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
 <notifications xmlns="http://BLAH.com/outbound">
  <OrganizationId>BLAH</OrganizationId>
  <ActionId>BLAH</ActionId>
  <SessionId xsi:nil="true"/>
  <EnterpriseUrl>https://BLAH.com/</EnterpriseUrl>
  <PartnerUrl>https://BLAH.com/</PartnerUrl>
  <Notification>
   <Id>BLAH</Id>
   <sObject xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.BLAH.com" xsi:type="sf:Case">
    <sf:Id>BLAH</sf:Id>
    <sf:CaseNumber>BLAH</sf:CaseNumber>
    <sf:Case_Owner_ID_hidden__c>BLAH</sf:Case_Owner_ID_hidden__c>
    <sf:CreatedDate>2010-03-17T12:11:33.000Z</sf:CreatedDate>
    <sf:LastModifiedDate>2010-03-17T15:21:29.000Z</sf:LastModifiedDate>
    <sf:OwnerId>BLAH</sf:OwnerId>
    <sf:Status>BLAH</sf:Status>
   </sObject>
  </Notification>
 </notifications>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I think you'd get a fatal error for out-of-memory if you were hitting the memory limit. I thought it could have been post_max_size but I wouldn't expect that to truncate the data, it should just give you nothing

Comment: Which line does the PHP error occur in?

Comment: After the update there is no error in PHP, it was cause by fread filesize limitation. Now the error is on the SF side of things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PHP memory issue will say

```
PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 250871808)...
```

This is more likely to be incorrectly terminated or truncated data originating from the Salesforce platform - try debugging the first error from SF.

EDIT:

OK, it looks like you're grabbing data in an antiquated manner. Try replacing `fread()` with `stream_get_contents()`, and also `echo $content` straight after you get it to check the output.

Comment: yep that's what I did in the update, it's working now but having issues with Salesforce and Acknowledging the bulk request. I've seen some say that you could send the ACK file for the whole SOAP message but I can only get it to work if I do it for each message. I know thats another question but any thoughts?